# (jQuery) How to animate the elements inside a scrollable div when they come into sight on scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my whole HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/WgL9z/

I'm building a chat from scratch. I have a scrollable div containing divs, one for every message that has been sent. Something like

```
<div>
    (undefined number of divs pertaining to the same class)
</div>
```

I want to animate the messages so that they become visible/invisible while scrolling, ideally not allowing that a message can be seen partially. Messages should either be seen or not, not be half-there the way they can be now.

As it is a chat, the messages pile up, so the scrolltop() will be increasing,and the height of each message is also variable depending on how much text it has, so I have no idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand what you mean. Here's my solution to your problem: [http://jsfiddle.net/silveraven/WgL9z/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/straszak_piotr/WgL9z/10/)

The most important things are:

**CSS**:

```
#mesanjescont{
    position: relative;
}

.not-visible {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

.mensaje{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    /* Safari */
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

This will help you to create animated showing/hiding of elements.

```
JavaScript (I used jQuery 1.11.0):

if (mensajeTop + mensajeHeight > mensajescontHeight || mensajeTop + mensajeHeight < 0){
    $(this).addClass("not-visible");
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("not-visible");
}
```

This if-else statement determines whether the element is visible or not.