# How can I make my header fade out/disappear on scroll down and reappear on scroll up?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've already looked around for quite a bit and stumbled upon some tutorials, and so far, I've achieved not so much. What I'm trying to do is make the top header of my website disappear when the user scrolls down and reappear when they scroll to the top of the page.
My code so far:

```
  <header class="top-nav">
      <div class="top-nav">
      <!-- Top Row -->
      <div class="top">  
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row vh-center">   
            <div class="col-md-5 slogan">
               Plumbing and Remodelling Services.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">          
              <a href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 top-social right">
              <div class="social-3 right">
                <a href="index.html#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="index.html#"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a>
                <a href="index.html#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="index.html#"><i class="icon-tumblr"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
           <!-- Top Row End -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var didScroll;
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var delta = 5;
        var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            didScroll = true;
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            if (didScroll) {
                hasScrolled();
                didScroll = false;
            }
        }, 250);

        function hasScrolled() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
                return;

            if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
                $('header').removeClass('top-nav').addClass('nav-up');
            } else {
                if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('top-nav');
                }
            }

        lastScrollTop = st;
        }
    </script>
</div>
</header>

<header id="home">
    <!-- Navigation --> 
        <div class="navigation">    

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row vh-center">   

                <ul class="nav" id="nav">
                    <li>
              <!-- Menu Link -->
                        <a href="index.html#home" title="About">
                            <span>About</span>
                        </a>
              <!-- Menu Link End -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.terrylove.com/forums/index.php" title="Forums" target='_blank'>
                            <span>Forums</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#event" title="Something">
                            <span>Renovations?</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#portfolio" title="Something">
                            <span>Plumbing?</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#team" title="Something">
                            <span>Stories?</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#blog" title="Something">
                            <span>Pricing</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html#contact" title="Contact">
                            <span>Contact</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          <select class="select-menu"></select> <!-- select menu for small screens -->

        </div> 
      </div> 

    </div>          
    <!-- Navigation End -->    
  </header>
```

The CSS:

```
header {
  margin:0px auto;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  float:left;  
  background: #34373d;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}
```

When I scroll down, both the headers are just fixed and don't do what I'm saying (of course I haven't told the second header to do anything, I'll implement that once I've gotten the first one to function)
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/Atckq) helps you

jQuery

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {

var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st < lastScrollTop){
            $('.navbar ').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('.navbar ').fadeOut();
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
  })
```

Comment: I did, unfortunately it still just does nothing for me.

Comment: Alright, although it works, it sort of doesn't. It disappears on scroll down, but reappears every scroll up. How can I choose when exactly it should disappear and reappear?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Your code works perfect for my top header, but I'm using this code for the bottom navigation bar: http://pastebin.com/qRiDHrFb and I was wanting this to only scroll down/up when I choose, which I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I allways use jQuery's scrollTop for these actions.

```
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        toggleHeader();
    });

    function toggleHeader() {
        $('header').toggle( $(window).scrollTop() < 50 );
    }
```

Comment: Okay cool, so how would you implement this? Should I just replace the script above with this?

Comment: Yes, replace the '50' with the position where the header should hide/show.

Comment: I tried that, and still it doesn't do anything on scroll. http://pastebin.com/38av9DZh

Answer (score 0):

I've answered recently for very similar question. After little modification it should fit your needs: [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602201/jquery-how-to-animate-the-elements-inside-a-scrollable-div-when-they-come-into/24606176#24606176)

Direct link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/silveraven/WgL9z/10/

```
Code just to put jsfiddle link...
```